# Error in the program to swap two numbers using Pointers

Tags: c

A few years back i was working with Turbo C compiler and the following code worked fine on it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
     int a=2,b=3;
     swap(a,b);
     printf("%d\n%d\n",a,b);
}

swap(int *x,int *y)
{
     int t;
     //x=malloc(2);
     //y=malloc(2);
     t=*x;
     *x=*y;
     *y=t;
     printf("%d\n%d\n",x,y);
}
```

Now i am working on cygwin and if i run this code i get an error `Segmentation fault(core dumped)`
If i uncomment the malloc statements i get the output

```
536937064
536937080
2
3
```

Are first two lines of output some garbage values? What exactly is happening here and how can i get the correct output?

Comment: Have you noticed you warning message in compiling?

Comment: the only warning message is that main should be of type int

Comment: you compiler is so powerful. It can even use `swap` before definition or declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Here](http://ideone.com/8lOp1)** is the corrected version of your program, which will execute correctly.

There are a number of things going wrong in the sample you posted:

### **Incorrect Argument type being passed:**

```
swap(a,b);
```

should be :

```
swap(&a,&b);
```

Your function expects pointer to the integers to be modified, You are not doing so.

---

### **Incorrect Format specifiers for `printf`:**

```
printf("%d\n%d\n",x,y);
```

should be:

```
printf("%d\n%d\n",*x,*y);
```

`printf` is not type safe and you need to ensure you use proper format specifiers while using it. Using incorrect format specifiers results in **Undefined Behavior**.

---

The next two are good practices if not errors and you should follow them.

### **Incorrect return type of `main()`:**

As per the Standard a program should return `int`,

```
void main()
```

should be

```
int main()
```

Also, add return a value `return 0;`at the end of `main`.

---

### **Function Declaration:**

You should declare the function `swap()` correctly before `main`:

```
void swap(int *x,int *y);
```

Providing a function declaration before the place where you use it in code, gives the compiler a opportunity to match the parameters and report incorrect types being passed.

---

Further using `malloc` as you have would not acheive what you are trying to achieve, You do not need to use `malloc` here at all and One should always avoid using it as much as possible.

Also, You should pick up a **[good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)** and learn the basics.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing here is actually correct.

1. The parameters to `swap` are the literal addresses 2 and 3. You can `&a` and `&b` in the call.
2. `printf` in `swap` is printing the pointer addresses, so the output is "expected".
3. If you were using `malloc` (why?), you are only allocating 2 bytes. An int is generally 4 , but please use `sizeof`.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing values of the variables and using pointers to receive it.

```
`swap(a,b) `
```

should be `swap(&a,&b)`

because you must pass the address of the variables, not the variable itself. Read Call by reference in C.